# Laravel Dusk: Wait for a load mask/overlay to finish

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I am having difficulty getting some tests to pass because of a load mask I put over the entire screen during AJAX calls (transparent black with a loading gif in the middle).

I can get it to work if I `pause(2000)` each time, but the amount of AJAX calls in the app make that the slow solution. I am trying to use `waitUntilMissing` but it's not working.

- I have a `div` with two classes: `load-mask` and `loading`.
- `load-mask` is always there
- `loading` class applied to div during all vue.js AJAX calls; this is the load mask
- When AJAX response received, `loading` class removed

So in my test I am trying to do this:

```
$browser->loginAs($this->user)
    ->visit(new CustomInputPage)
    ->saveNarrative('Lorem ipsum dolor')
    ->visit(new CustomInputPage)
    ->waitUntilMissing('.load-mask')
    ->assertSee('Lorem ipsum dolor');
```

- Load a page
- Enter text & hit save
- reload page
- make sure text is still there

I get an error on the `assertSee` because once the page loads, the `loading` is applied as it makes it's AJAX call so it hasn't loaded the text yet.

I am assuming `waitForMissing('.load-mask')` is passing before the load mask even starts, so it tries to `assertSee` during the loading process, but it's an assumption.

Is there a working solution outside just using `pause`?

**EDIT:** I am currently trying to click around the page to reload the AJAX instead of a full page load. I am still experiencing the same issue.

Now I am trying this instead:

```
$browser->loginAs($this->user)
    ->visit(new CustomInputPage)
    ->saveNarrative('Lorem ipsum dolor')
    ->clickLink('Tab 2')
    ->waitUntilMissing('.load-mask')
    ->assertSee('Lorem ipsum dolor');
```

Clicking a tab will load the AJAX call I'm referring to. I notice in the screenshot it's always showing my `.loading` animation.

So...`Tab 2` should be an empty box but the screenshot shows the text hasn't been cleared yet and load mask is still present (happens after response is received).

So I can't get the timing on a completed AJAX call down without using `pause`. Should I try another way?

**EDIT 2**

Here is where my load mask is being inserted. The vue.js axios library.

```
import store from '../store';

let numberOfAjaxCAllPending = 0;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // Do something before request is sent
  numberOfAjaxCAllPending++;
  store.commit('isLoading', true);
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  numberOfAjaxCAllPending = 0;
  store.commit('isLoading', false);
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

  // Do something with response data
  numberOfAjaxCAllPending--;
  if (numberOfAjaxCAllPending === 0) {
    store.commit('isLoading', false);
  }
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  numberOfAjaxCAllPending = 0;
  store.commit('isLoading', false);
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

And on each Laravel blade template, I tried this first:

```
<div :class="{ loading: $store.state.isLoading }" class="load-mask"></div>
```

But now I am trying this way, with the loading class always present and just toggling display none/block

```
<div :style="{display: $store.getters.getLoadingDisplay }" class="loading"></div>
```

Same issue occurs this way as well. The load mask is present and I am also noticing the text box isn't being cleared when switching tabs in Laravel Dusk (the tabs clear fine in a regular browser).

**EDIT 3**

The first assertion passes, then it fails when trying to `->press('Save')`. I get this error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mt-3 btn-primary" style="float: left;">...</button> is not clickable at point (440, 912). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading" style="display: block;"></div>
```

This is the test I am trying to run. As you can see, I have a `waitUntilMissing` and an `assertMissing` right after each other. Then I press `Save` and it says there's still a load mask. If I wait 2 seconds before the `keys` statement, it works fine.

```
$browser->loginAs($this->user)
  ->visit(new CustomInputPage)
  ->waitUntilMissing('.loading')
  ->assertMissing('.loading')
  ->keys('.ql-editor', 'Test Text')
  ->press('Save')
  ->waitUntilMissing('.loading');
```

Comment: What does the error screenshot show?

Comment: It shows my screen as expected with the load mask still present. If I pause for 2 seconds, load mask is no longer there.

Comment: Added more info to OP

Comment: Where exactly are you inserting the pauses?

Comment: Added EDIT 2 above showing the `axios` code